# How to execute functions in different threads in Swift?

Tags: multithreading, swift, xcode6

I'm using three functions, an I need use in differents threads, because when I execute one function, the function that show in view crash..

I'm trying this code:

when actions is a function, but this crash too using this code

```
        var concurrentQueue: dispatch_queue_t =
            dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, {
            self.actions()

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                println("Completed")
                });
        })
```

What are I doing?

Thanks!!

Comment: What are the error messages? What happens if you replace `self.actions()` with just `println("Doing stuff")`?

Comment: if I replace self.actions() with println("Doing stuff") this show in console..

Comment: So the crash occurs in your function, and not in the code you've posted?

Comment: Yes, concretely the crash then I changed anything is that not show correctly the refresh in the view.. like a frozen view one-two seconds. For this reason I don't know if this return to first thread or how funtion this

Comment: what you are doing inside the actions() method. paste some code

Comment: AVFoundation session video, and visual components like labels..